# C# async persistent WebClient example

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, webclient, persistent

I need to make a simple http client in C# that must be asynchronous and must support a persistent connection to the server. So i'm trying to use the WebClient class, but i'm having some problems, my code is this:

```
void sendMessage()
{
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(bypassAllCertificateStuff);

  string loginRequest = @"{'IDENTIFIER':'patient1','PASSWORD':'asdasd','DEVICE_ID':'knt-01'}";

  client = new WebClient();         

  // add event handlers for completed and progress changed
  client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_UploadProgressChanged);
  client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadStringCompleted);
  client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);

  // carry out the operation as normal

  client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("Https://192.168.1.100/PaLogin"), "POST", loginRequest);
}

void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("downloadProgressChanged");
}

void client_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
   if (e.ProgressPercentage != 50)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("uploadProgressChanged");
   }
}

void client_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result != null)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

The problem is that i should receive a response from the server, but neither the client_UploadStringCompleted nor client_DownloadProgressChanged callbacks are ever called.
The only thing I see on the console is: client_DownloadProgressChanged

So basically what i'm trying to do is:

1- I send some data to the server without closing the connection
2- I receive the server response but the connection must still be open when i have received it.

What am I missing?

Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the whole HTTP protocol here.

HTTP is a **stateless request-response** protocol. HTTP 1.1 provides *optional* guidelines for keeping connections open purely for the sake of performance - although as for the request response paradigm, there is no change. *[Yet I have seen many cases where client or server have decided not to respect it and closed the connection.]* It also provides chunked encoding to facilitate streaming, but that is all it is as far as HTTP is concerned.

So basically in HTTP, client will wait for a reply (and keep connection open) until it receives a response or timeout. There is no way to change/better this behaviour.

NOW, back to you problem.
I think something is going wrong with connecting to the server so you need to use Fiddler to see what is happening. My hunch is it does not connect to server (firewall, server down, etc) since the certificate check is not even called.

Comment: To expand on this, `Connection: Keep-Alive` will cause the TCP connection to remain open after the HTTP transaction completes, and the client may use this existing connection to send another HTTP request, instead of making a new connection.

Comment: True. Yet I have seen many cases where client or server have decided not to respect it and closed the connection.

Comment: `Connection: Keep-Alive` is designed to **request** a keep alive. You can't rely on support. If the server doesn't support it, or doesn't want to provide one, it will simply close the connection. If the client later decides that it doesn't need the connection, it will close it. The same applies on the server side.

Comment: With apache httpclient on clientside and the sun httpserver for the server i'm able to do what i said, but the apache httpclient is written in java and i need to find something similar in c#

Answer (score 0):

Http server push mechanism can do this. 
See this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

c# client:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(uri), Encoding.UTF8, true))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

(che è quello che vi dicevo questo pomeriggio)